# HTTP Post request to GCM server always returning "NotRegistered"

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-messaging

```
 var options = 
    { 
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization':'key=VALUE'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        "to" : gcmId,
        "data" : {
            message: message
        },
        })
    }
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if(error) console.log(error);
        console.log("RESPONSE STATUS: " + response.statusCode)
        console.log("BODY: " + body);
        });
```

Am I placing my registration id (gcmId) in the correct place? I seem to always be receiving:

`{"multicast_id":9098772304322316557,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}`

Starting to think it's a backend problem.

Comment: which module you are using in node.js for sending gcm notifications

Comment: `var request = require('request');`

Comment: don't you think the header should be 'Authorization':'key=' + VALUE instead of 'Authorization':'key=VALUE'

Comment: i'm not receiving any authorization errors.

Comment: u tried changing it...??

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream according to that its `Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA`

Comment: you are sending the word "VALUE" as your authorization key not the content of the variable VALUE.

Comment: i'm sending the actual value in my code, I'm not trying to share my api key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)...

> If it is NotRegistered, you should remove the registration ID from your server database because the application was uninstalled from the device, or the client app isn't configured to receive messages.

That appropriately answers your question.

Here the list of [all possible error code](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)in GCM which again says the following about **NotRegistered error**.

> An existing registration token may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:

- If the client app unregisters with GCM.
  If the client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if the user uninstalls the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
- If the registration token expires (for example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens, or the APNS token has expired for iOS devices).
- If the client app is updated but the new version is not configured to receive messages.
  For all these cases, remove this registration token from the app server and stop using it to send messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
var gcmIds  = [ "GCM_ID_1", "GCM_ID_2" ];
var GCM_API_KEY = "MY_API_KEY";

var options =
{
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':'key=' + GCM_API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "registration_ids" : gcmIds,
        "data" : {
            message: "Test Messages"
        },
    })
}
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if(error) console.log(error);
    console.log("RESPONSE STATUS: " + response.statusCode)
    console.log("BODY: " + body);
});
```

Comment: you need to send to use "registration_ids" instead of "to"