# SocketIO "NotRegistered" message when using io.sockets.emit

Tags: android, ios, node.js, sockets

Recently an application I built using SocketIO stopping sending messages to clients out of the blue, and the message `NotRegistered` appears in the console whenever a message is sent. Everything else works fine, and the server has no trouble receiving requests.

One quick thing to note, the only clients having issues are ones on mobile devices (e.g iOS/Android) using the respective native mobile socket.io library.

```
io.sockets.emit("newMessage", {removed: removed, room: room, userID: removed, name: removed, message: messageContent});
```

Comment: What is the exact and complete message you see?

Comment: @jfriend00 That was the complete message

Comment: Are you seeing the message on your server or in your Android client?  Do you know if your clients are using a webSocket or xhrpolling as the transport?

Comment: @jfriend00 It's on the server console, and I have no idea

Comment: Are you using Google Cloud Messaging anywhere in your server?  Might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718115/gcm-error-not-registered and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344720/http-post-request-to-gcm-server-always-returning-notregistered

Answer (score 0):

The `NotRegistered` console message comes from a FCM/GCM token being invalid, and the clients receiving the messages were two completely separate client side bugs (Missing variables and a typo).